# C# Messy Function - Refactoring

Tags: c#

Just started to clean up an old code base.
I'm interested in your perspective and ways that you would change the following function.

```
    private void MarkSelectedRow()
    {
        Object obj = Bankkonto1.Value;
        if ((obj != null) && (myBankkonten.Contains(obj.ToString())))
        {
            foreach (UltraGridRow myRow in Bankkonto1.Rows)
            {
                if (myRow.Cells[STR_Id].Text != obj.ToString()) 
                    continue;

                myRow.Selected = true;
                try
                {
                    hV_OPPanel1.SetBankListe(myBankkonten, Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index);
                }
                catch
                {}
                return;
            }
            if (Bankkonto1.Rows.Count > 0)
                Bankkonto1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
        }
        else
            SelectDefaultBank();

        try
        {
            Bankkonto2.Rows[Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index].Selected = true;
            BankkontoS.Rows[Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index].Selected = true;
            AutoBank.Rows[Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index].Selected = true;
            hV_OPPanel1.SetBankListe(myBankkonten, Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index);
        }
        catch
        {}
    }


    public void SetBankListe(BankAccountList bankliste, int SelectedIndex)
    {

        if (OPBankkonto.DataSource != bankliste)
            OPBankkonto.SetDataBinding(bankliste, "");

        OPBankkonto.ValueMember = "Id";
        OPBankkonto.DisplayMember = "DisplayText";
        OPBankkonto.DataBind();
        OPBankkonto.Rows[SelectedIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: To be honest, I don't find this function that messy. I am completely unfamiliar with the code-base (obviously) yet with 30 seconds reading I can figure out what the function is doing. I'd suggest your time would be better spent elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider inverting the first if to make it simpler and quicker to be aware of the else.

---

I strongly suggest *always* leaving something inside a catch - if you have nothing else to put there at least leave a comment.

---

I would change

```
if (Bankkonto1.Rows.Count > 0)
```

to, `using System.Linq;` :

```
if (Bankkonto1.Rows.Any())
```

---

I would save reused values in scoped variables:

```
string objValue = obj.ToString();
...
int selectedRow = Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index;
```

---

I would consider refactoring the foreach

```
        foreach (UltraGridRow myRow in Bankkonto1.Rows)
        {
            if (myRow.Cells[STR_Id].Text != obj.ToString()) 
                continue;
```

into a Linq select:

```
        var row = Bankkonto1.Rows.FirstOrdefault( r => r.Cells[STR_Id].Text == objValue);
        if(row != null) {
```

Comment: +1. However, I don't see the point of changing a simple property call into a LINQ extension method that starts to enumerate the items to find out if there are any...

Comment: I concur about the catch statements - if there is no need for something to be inside the statement at least have a comment explaining why.

Comment: My thought was that the extension could just step on the first item and return without counting the potentially infinite elements, or guess that `.Count` was cached and faster based on the type and return `.Count != 0`, or... that is, I left the optimization decision for someone else who I expect (demand) to make a better judgement call than me. @Guffa I do this `.Any()` gimmick often. Should I not? (That is, are my reasons flawed?)

Comment: At the very least, a catch should look like: `catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex); }` to be able to see any issues under the debugger.  Next step up would be logging it appropriately via whatever logging framework in use.

Answer (score 5):

hm
there are quite a lot of `try-catch` wich don't do anything at all...
if there would be a massive exception you would just continue with what you are doing...

1. **Remove empty try-catch blocks** and replace it with propper checks
    If `Bankkonto2` in the lower section is null you wouldn't set Selected Property of Row `BankkontoS` due to the thrown exception before. In my code i want my exceptions to be seen or recorded by the system, so I can fix it. You don't know what else has gone wrong in that Method.
2. **Throw speaking exceptions** so any user can change his input to fullfill the requirements of the application or can create a new bugtracking issue with the propper information.
3. **Try using local Variables** instead of calling Properties over and over again. 
   Current you are using `Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index` 5 times. If the Propertycall `Bankkonto1.SelectedRow` takes about 0.5sec you are currently burning 2sec :-) Try redusing it where possible. It also gets more readable.

Youd could Trade:

```
if (myRow.Cells[STR_Id].Text != obj.ToString())
```

Against:

```
string currentCellText = myRow.Cells[STR_Id].Text;
string searchedCellText = obj.ToString();

if (currentCellText != searchedCellText)
```

Example for remocing the try-catch blocks:
Your Code:

```
try
{
    Bankkonto2.Rows[Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index].Selected = true;
    BankkontoS.Rows[Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index].Selected = true;
    AutoBank.Rows[Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index].Selected = true;
    hV_OPPanel1.SetBankListe(myBankkonten, Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index);
}
catch
{}
```

I would try something like:

```
if(Bankkonto1 ==null)
    throw new System.NullReferenceException("Bitte ein Bankkonto angeben!");

if(Bankkonto1.SelectedRow== null)
    throw new System.NullReferenceException("Bitte wählen Sie eine Zeile!");

int selectedIndex = Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index;

if (Bankkonto2 != null && selectedIndex < Bankkonto2.Rows.Count)
    Bankkonto2.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
if (BankkontoS != null && selectedIndex < BankkontoS.Rows.Count)
    BankkontoS.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
if (AutoBank != null && selectedIndex < AutoBank.Rows.Count)
    AutoBank.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
if(hV_OPPanel1 != null)
    hV_OPPanel1.SetBankListe(myBankkonten, selectedIndex);
```

I would refactor it something like this:

```
private void MarkSelectedRow() {

    if (Bankkonto1 == null)
        throw new System.NullReferenceException("Bitte ein Bankkonto angeben!");


    if (Bankkonto1.SelectedRow == null)
        throw new System.NullReferenceException("Bitte wählen Sie eine Zeile!");

    Object obj = Bankkonto1.Value;
    int selectedIndex = Bankkonto1.SelectedRow.Index;
    if ((obj != null) && (myBankkonten.Contains(obj.ToString()))) {
        foreach (UltraGridRow myRow in Bankkonto1.Rows) {

            string currentCellText = myRow.Cells[STR_Id].Text;
            string searchedCellText = obj.ToString();

            if (currentCellText != searchedCellText)
                continue;

            myRow.Selected = true;

            if(hV_OPPanel1 != null)
                hV_OPPanel1.SetBankListe(myBankkonten, selectedIndex );

            return;
        }

        if (Bankkonto1.Rows.Count > 0)
            Bankkonto1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
    } else
        SelectDefaultBank();

    if (Bankkonto2 != null && selectedIndex < Bankkonto2.Rows.Count)
        Bankkonto2.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
    if (BankkontoS != null && selectedIndex < BankkontoS.Rows.Count)
        BankkontoS.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
    if (AutoBank != null && selectedIndex < AutoBank.Rows.Count)
        AutoBank.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;

    if(hV_OPPanel1 != null)
         hV_OPPanel1.SetBankListe(myBankkonten, selectedIndex);

}
```

Hope i could help, please contact me if you have questions about my snippets or if you are interssted in my decisions. I would enjoy learning from you and also would be glad helping you!